# Passing PHP variable with ajax issue

Tags: php, ajax

I want to pass php variables containing order id and customer id with javascript to a php file but when I use var dump to check data php returns ( string(43) "")

Following code I tried to pass variables:

PHP file with html code and button calling js function:

```
while ($orders = mysqli_fetch_array($orderList)) {
    $orderId        = $orders['order_id'];
    $CustId         = $orders['car_id'];
    $orderPrice     = $orders['order_price'];
    $orderStatus    = $orders['order_state'];
    $orderDate      = $orders['order_date'];
    $trackId        = $orders['track_id'];

    echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $sr++ . "</td>
        <td>$orderId</td>
        <td>$trackId</td>
        <td>$CustId</td>
        <td>$orderStatus</td>
        <td>$orderPrice</td>
        <td>$orderDate</td>
        <td class='btn-group-horizontal'>
        <a href='order-details.php?action=view&order_id=$orderId&cust_id=$CustId' title='View Order or Edit Order'><i class='btn btn-info fa fa-eye'></i></a>
        <a href='order-details.php?action=view&order_id=$orderId&cust_id=$CustId' title='Edit Order'><i class='btn btn-primary fa fa-pencil'></i></a>
        <a href='#' title='Delete Order'><i class='btn btn-danger fa fa-trash-o'></i></a>
        <button type='button' onclick='backendDeleteOrder();'>Delete</button>
        </td>
        </tr>";
}
```

JS code Passing PHP variables:

```
function backendDeleteOrder(){

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "functions/delete.php?action=backendDeleteOrder";
    var orderID = "<?php echo $orderId;?>";
    var custId = "<?php echo $CustId;?>";

    var vars = "orderID=" + orderID + "&custId=" + custId;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("statusOrder").innerHTML = return_data;
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("statusOrder").innerHTML = "Processing...! Please Wait.";
}
```

PHP file receiving js data:

```
// I also tried POST here like.
//$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : "";

$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

if ($action == 'backendDeleteOrder') {
    $orderId = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['orderID']);
    $custId = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['custId']);

    var_dump($custId.$orderId);
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: The 43 in `string(43) ""` indicates the string length, so it is non-empty. I notice in some areas you are using `$custId` and others `$CustId`, which are case-sensitive and therefore different. It's not clear what the full program flow is to tell if it matters in your context. But since the var_dump() indicates a non-empty string, var_dump() each of those variables separately to determine which ones have a length, then figure out what they contain. When you place the two PHP variables into `var` declarations in JS, when you view the page source, are the values present and correct?

Comment: i think you wanted to use `var_dump($custId , $orderId);` using  `.` (dot) operator will concatenate the two numbers to a string.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Sir, values are correct in php file but unable to get values in 3rd file

Comment: Please check the output from `var_dump($_POST);` also `var_dump($_GET);` inside `delete.php`. Place it at the top, before anything else.  The `$_GET` seems it is correct already, because your original `var_dump()` would have no output otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Sir, i tried `var_dump($_POST);` it returns `array(1) { ["trackId"]=> string(22) "" } ` also tried  `var_dump($_GET);` it returns `array(1) { ["action"]=> string(18) "backendDeleteOrder" }`

Comment: Your POST only contains `trackId`, but the JS form you are posting from does not have that key. Are you sure you var_dump()ed the right script at the right time? The `backendDeleteOrder` appears correct, but you should not see `trackId` in that form at all if you are using the code as you have posted above.